# Openssh не удаляется

Tags: ssh, ubuntu

Обновил openssl отпал ssh. Пытались слить всеми способами ответ -> пермишен денайд, нет возможности слить сам исполняемый файл(не выдать ему права, вообще ничего с ним сделать нельзя)(PS, я под рутом) погуглили ничего хорошего не нашлось. Может кто то сталкивался/OS: Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для удаления подобного файла, на нем надо изменить права.

[root]# chmod 4775 file_name

При этом веса этих битов для получения нужного суммарного результата задаются следующим образом:

```
4 — "бит смены идентификатора пользователя",2 — "бит смены идентификатора группы",1 — "бит сохранения задачи (sticky bit)".
```

Пробуйте вводить не три цифры прав, а полный сбор с битностью на смену владельца файла.

Также возможно понадобиться пройтись командой chgrp, что бы убрать жестко привязку группы на файл.

Comment: На файле висели два атрибута chattr -i filechattr -a file